# Will files created under source directory after running `cp` be copied?

Tags: files, cp, file-copy, concurrency

Suppose I use `cp` to copy a directory to another place. If the process takes long, and I create a new file under the source directory, will it be copied, or does it depend on something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new file while `cp` is operating, it's likely that it won't be picked up. That might depend on the `cp` implementation: some gather a list of files when they start, others do it by chunks. If it's a recursive copy, all the `cp` implementations I've seen work directory by directory, so if you add the file to a directory that `cp` hasn't traversed yet, it will be copied.

If you add a file midway and you want to copy it, run `rsync` afterwards (after the copy is finished and the new file is fully written). Rsync will only copy the added file.

You can run rsync from the start (use `rsync -a` to do a recursive copy and preserve metadata). Rsync can do pretty much everything `cp` can do and much more, so you can ignore `cp` and always use `rsync` if you like (except on embedded systems that don't have `rsync`).